# Should we continue to use "The Stack Exchange Network" on the Chat FAQ text?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-faq

I saw today that the site still refers to itself as "The Stack Exchange Network" in some places but I'm not sure if that's correct, current terminology.

Here is an example from  the [Chat FAQ page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq). The entire page pretty much exclusively reads "The Stack Exchange Network", which seems a bit much. At the very least, I feel that removing the "the" from the title is appropriate, which would remove such oddities as the double "the" in the example below:

[image: Chat FAQ Text]

Even on the [Terms of Service/Legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) page, "The" is not included as part of the network name:

[image: Terms of Service/Legal page]

As you can see in the image above, "the" is either absent or not capitalized  - yes, it's capitalized when it's the first word in the sentence but that's different.

I believe that, for the purposes of site consistency, "The" should be dropped from the "The Stack Exchange Network" usage on the Chat FAQ.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a FR or a discussion... so feel free to retag if you like. I'm also not sure if "site-faq" is correct, or if it should be "chat-faq".

Comment: "the The Stack Exchange Network" certainly does sounds strange.

Comment: I'm also sort of curious about the general use of "Network" so much on this page... I feel that the "network" is often implied, so I wonder if people think it's still necessary.

Comment: And, to be completely honest, one doesn't have to be a member of the "Stack Exchange Network"... I don't even know what that means... you simply have to be a member of *a* Stack Exchange site to use the Chat rooms.

Comment: To confuse your tagging even more, typos can go under the tag [tag:bug] (I think) ;-)

Comment: Yes, agree with @Shokhet. I've seen a lot of [grammar questions tagged "bug"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+grammar).